# Save Button Margin Thickness in Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties

Right Now I'm storing 4 properties as:

```
Button1L Double 10
Button1R Double 10
Button1T Double 10
Button1B Double 10
```

In Constructor

```
Button1.Margin = new Thickness(Properties.Setting.Default.Button1L, ...);
```

To Save

```
Properties.Setting.Default.Button1L = 20;
.
.
.
Properties.Setting.Default.Save();
```

This is working Fine but my issue is  have almost 20 Buttons for which I can not define 4 properties for each.

So my question is is there any way to store thickness as `{L,T,R,B}` or  by applying some loop and creating dynamic setting variable  by itself and assigning them on new run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your class where have you done this.

Comment: I have not used any class as of now just implemented in my code behind for testing 1 button  @DeshDeepSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use `Thickness` as type of a Setting.

Choose `Browse...` from the list of available types:

[image]

Then select the `PresentationFramework` assembly, and from there the namespace `System.Windows`, where you'll find the type `Thickness`:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: I tried to look for Thickness inside the System.Window but was not there

Comment: Got It i was looking inside WindowBase instead of PresenttionFramework

Comment: Can I use single Property  for multiple Buttons as well or have to create specific variables for all buttons?

Comment: You can of course use the same setting for all Buttons.

Comment: +1 For the use of `Browse...`. I had noticed it multiple times but never actually found a use until I saw this answer.

Comment: @Clemens but won't all the buttons will then start with only 1 location?

Comment: Margins are not meant for positioning elements. You would instead use suitable layout Panels like Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ThicknessConverter. It has a function ConvertFrom() which can be used to get a thickness from string:

```
var converter = new ThicknessConverter();
var thickness = converter.ConvertFrom("1;2;3;4");
```

which will parse the thickness from a string. Please note that it will not accept **','** as delimiter depending on the current culture, so using **';'** should be safe.

Using this approach you can simplify your configuration as you will only need one string Property/Value for each button instead of four individual double values which can save some work.

So in your case you would use it in the following way:

```
var converter = new ThicknessConverter();
Button1.Margin = (Thickness)converter.ConvertFrom(Properties.Setting.Default.Button1);
```

where ***Properties.Setting.Default.Button1*** will be a string Property containing the margin definition

To store the values you would use something like this:

```
string strValue = converter.ConvertToString(Properties.Setting.Default.Button1.Margin);
```

Comment: can you eloborate a bit?

Comment: won't it will throw exception for type conversion?

Comment: thanks yes its working but will the process to store the margin will  be same as well?

Answer (score 0):

If the names of your Buttons match the names of the properties, you can use reflection.

1. Find all properties that are of type `Button`
2. Store all `Button` objects in a collection
3. Loop through every button

   In that loop find the properties of the default properties object depending on the current button's name. Append L, R, T or B to the name and use reflection to find and set the property accordingly.

   You can combine this approach with @DenisThomas answer. Then you only have to find one property instead of four inside the loop.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, 
+1 for explaining the process in simple way
but actually the step 1 that you are talking about i tried with with findchildren but was unable to find them.
Can you help with that

Answer (score -3):

You must crate class that inherit from `button`,  then you can add a `constructor` to class for your purpose.

Another way is exist in new dot net version,
New way is `extension method`

Comment: this is not what I was looking for